# Firebase Database retrieve delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that registers a username and some other info from the user, But when I try to load the users info in his/her profile in `onCreateView()` there is a little delay for 3.5 seconds. Is there any efficient and reliable way when retrieving a users data from Firebase and adding it to a `TextView` or some any other views?

> Here is what I have done so far, I am using a Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    //Some views initialized here

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference();
    ref.child(path)
            .child(user.getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    init(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can activate the firebase offline for the user data `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` but you must be careful cause if the auth token expires while your app is offline, the client pauses write operations until your app re-authenticates the user, otherwise the write operations might fail due to security rules. check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)